# FirebaseMessaging FIS_AUTH_ERROR

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, firebase-cloud-messaging

**I try initialize Firebase Messaging and get token, but I receive this error**

```
Future<void> _firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler(RemoteMessage message)  async {
  print('on Background Message : ${message.data}');
}
class MyHttpOverrides extends HttpOverrides {
  @override
  HttpClient createHttpClient(SecurityContext context) {
    return super.createHttpClient(context)..badCertificateCallback = (X509Certificate cert, String host, int port) => true;
  }
}
final FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin = FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();

Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  await GlobalConfiguration().loadFromAsset("configurations");


  NotificationSettings settings = await  FirebaseMessaging.instance.requestPermission(
    alert: true,
    announcement: false,
    badge: true,
    carPlay: false,
    criticalAlert: false,
    provisional: false,
    sound: true,
  );

  await FirebaseMessaging.instance.setForegroundNotificationPresentationOptions(
    alert: true,
    badge: true,
    sound: true,
  );

  if (settings.authorizationStatus == AuthorizationStatus.authorized) {
    print('User granted permission');
  } else if (settings.authorizationStatus == AuthorizationStatus.provisional) {
    print('User granted provisional permission');
  } else {
    print('User declined or has not accepted permission');
  }
try{
  await FirebaseMessaging.instance.getToken();

  FirebaseMessaging.instance.getInitialMessage();
  if(GetPlatform.isMobile){
    FirebaseMessaging.instance.subscribeToTopic('suitableUser');
  }else{
  }

  FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((event) {
  }).onError((error){
    print('error');
  });

  FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp.listen((event) {
    print('success : ${event.data}');
  }).onError((error){
    print('error');
  });

  FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(_firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler);
}catch(e){
    print('555555 FirebaseMessaging ::: $e');
}


  HttpOverrides.global = new MyHttpOverrides();
  runApp(MyApp());
}
```

**I have tried many methods such as deleting the build file, downloading Json file from firebase again, and creating another API, but i get this error in run**

```
E/FirebaseInstanceId(13464): Failed to get FIS auth token
    E/FirebaseInstanceId(13464): Caused by: com.google.firebase.installations.FirebaseInstallationsException: Firebase Installations Service is unavailable. Please try again later.
    E/FirebaseInstanceId(13464):    at com.google.firebase.installations.remote.FirebaseInstallationServiceClient.createFirebaseInstallation(FirebaseInstallationServiceClient.java:153)
    E/FirebaseInstanceId(13464):    at com.google.firebase.installations.FirebaseInstallations.registerFidWithServer(FirebaseInstallations.java:530)
    E/FirebaseInstanceId(13464):    at com.google.firebase.installations.FirebaseInstallations.doNetworkCallIfNecessary(FirebaseInstallations.java:385)
    E/FirebaseInstanceId(13464):    at com.google.firebase.installations.FirebaseInstallations.lambda$doRegistrationOrRefresh$2$FirebaseInstallations(FirebaseInstallations.java:374)
    E/FirebaseInstanceId(13464):    at com.google.firebase.installations.-$$Lambda$FirebaseInstallations$VZq1h0TBcWNH8Y5yY86ujrFFyLo.run(Unknown Source:4)
    E/FirebaseInstanceId(13464):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.processTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1187)
    E/FirebaseInstanceId(13464):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1152)
    E/FirebaseInstanceId(13464):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
    E/FirebaseInstanceId(13464):    ... 1 more
    E/FirebaseInstanceId(13464): Topic sync or token retrieval failed on hard failure exceptions: FIS_AUTH_ERROR. Won't retry the operation.
    I/flutter (13464): 555555 FirebaseMessaging ::: [firebase_messaging/unknown] java.io.IOException: FIS_AUTH_ERROR
```

**Note: I use this code in another application and it works efficiently without any error**